# Using >= even though it's impossible for > to be true

Tags: python

I can't find an answer to this question either because it doesn't exist or because I am incapable of searching for it correctly.

Consider this code which prints out the numbers from 1 to 12 ad infinitum:

```
month = 1
while True:
    print(month)
    month += 1
    
    if month == 13:  # month >= 13 ? month > 12 ?
        month = 1
```

Is there any reason that the line `if month == 13` shouldn't be written as `if month > 12`, you know, "just in case?" I feel like it's "safer" to write `if month > 12` or `if month >= 13`, but I *know* that `month > 13` will *never* be true. Is there any agreed-upon best practice in a situation like this?

To be clear, I'm not looking for a way to improve this specific code. I'm looking for guidance on what I should do in this situation (and others like it).

Comment: "I know that `month > 13` will never be true": it's possible https://stackoverflow.com/q/2580933. "what I should do in this situation": use the `%` (modulus) operator

Comment: I find those alternatives misleading, as they suggest that it *can* be larger than 13. I find `== 13` much clearer.